# Javax : Try to find a solution to open an AVI within jar

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource, jmf

I tried to open an AVI within the executable jar file, the only solution I found is to use FileOutputStream and to make a copy in a temporary file :

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePathInJar);
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
this.file = new File("c:\\tmpfile.avi");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}
inputStream.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

And then I can make :

```
mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new File("c:\\tmpfile.avi").toURI().toURL());
```

**First question : Do you have any better solution?**

So with this solution I would delete the temporary file at the end of his use and I tried :

```
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.close();
mediaPlayer.deallocate();
file.delete()
```

But deletion doesn't work. It seems to be always in use in the player...

**Second question : How can I stop the use of the temporary file or force to delete?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but you could try using  `getClass().getResource(filePathInJar)` to get a URL for the resource, and then use that to construct a `MediaLocator` to use as the parameter to `createRealizedPlayer()`. Something like:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource(filePathInJar);
MediaLocator locator = new MediaLocator(url);
mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(locator);
```

Edit: 
So, I've verified that MediaLocator cannot deal with a jar:file:/ url.
It seems to me that you have two choices:

1. Find or create a custom InputStream-based DataSource. The page at http://www.extollit.com/isdsjmf.php claims to have one that works. I haven't tried it.
2. Keep doing what you're doing now - copy the media file from the jar to a temp file, and use a file:// url.
   I think that you can solve your problem with deleting the file by using File.createTempFile() and File.deleteOnExit()

Comment: getClass().getResourceAsStream(filePathInJar) return an InputStream object not an URL object it's why I have to copy the content of the InputStream to a file to get then the URL of this new file.

Comment: Use getResource instead of getResourceAsStream. Sorry for the typo in the code snippet - I corrected it.

Comment: I already try with getResource instead of getResourceAsStream but getResource doesn't work for a file within a jar...

Comment: getResource from a jar file absolutely works. whether MediaLocator can successfully use the returned URL is another question. What errors do you get when you try this?

Comment: When I do `URL url = getClass().getResource(filePathInJar).toURI().toURL();
mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);` in Eclipse it's work but in a runnable jar the method `createRealizedPlayer` generate a `NoPlayerException` who tell me `Cannot find a Player for :jar:file:/C:/........`

Comment: For the first solution you provided it doesn't work it seem to work with only online file and not for local file, I have `NoPlayerException` who tell me `Cannot find a Player for: DataSource@5a4bf53e`, now I will try the second one.

Comment: So, For the second solution provided it doesn't work too because `Manager.createRealizedPlayer` doesn't work with a file created by `File.createTempFile()` it tell me `Failed to configure: com.sun.media.PlaybackEngine@41584807
  Bad header in the media: WAVE Parser: expected magic string WAVE, got AVI` and `deleteOnExit` doesn't work like `delete`...